# How to remove a portion of a string from the end of a field only using find-and-replace in Microsoft Access?

Tags: regex, replace, ms-access-2010

I have a field with names and some of them have a trailing space and letter (middle initial...) at the end that I am trying to remove using find and replace in Microsoft Access 2010.

Example:

```
Doe John A -> Doe John
Doe Jane B -> Doe Jane
```

Is this possible using "find and replace" in Microsoft Access?

I was able to look through the following Access tutorials but can't figure out how to get it to only remove them from the END of the field/string:

- [Examples of wildcards in use](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-the-find-and-replace-dialog-box-to-change-data-HA010075099.aspx#BM8)
- [Access wildcard character reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-wildcard-character-reference-HA010076601.aspx#BMansi89)
- [Replace using wildcards](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm)

My current find-and-replace will remove the entire string (because of the asterisk but without the asterisk - nothing is found) not just the trailing space and letter!

[image: Find and Replace with Microsoft Access]

I think I am missing a "$" somewhere to tell it to only look at the end of the string but cannot get it to work without deleting the entire string from the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that find & replace dialog is sophisticated enough for what you want to do.  You could use a regular expression in VBA code, which should be a close match to what you want.  However this could be easy with SQL.

To display all of name_field except for the final space plus letter:

```
SELECT Left(name_field, Len(name_field)-2)
FROM MyTable
WHERE name_field Like "* [a-z]";
```

To actually discard the space plus letter from name_field:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET name_field = Left(name_field, Len(name_field)-2)
WHERE name_field Like "* [a-z]";
```